# Escape Newlines in Swift as a Raw String

Tags: json, swift, string, newline

I have a JSON string in **Swift 5** that is like this:

```
var text = """
{"ops": [{"insert": "Hello World!\n"},{"attributes": {"bold": true},"insert": "bold"},{"insert": "What if the "}, {"attributes": {"italic": true},"insert": "italic"}, {"insert": " text was awesome?\n\n"} ]}
"""
```

I pass that to a `WKWebView` where it is parsed with `JSON.parse(text)` so it can be rendered. At present, the JS complains that it's **invalid**. But if I manually edit the original string and replace all the `\n` with `\\n`, **it works**.

I need to turn `\n` into `\\n` programmatically and come out with a string on the other end.

I've tried this:

```
let raw = #"\#(text)"#
let ready = raw.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")
```

But it treats the newline characters as characters instead of as raw string elements.

It seems like this should be easy, but I can't see what I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: The `raw` thing is a red herring.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. It isn't necessarily an answer to my question, but it avoids the issue altogether.

Prior to sending the JSON data to the Javascript in the `WKWebView`, I encode it to a string using **Base64** encoding. This eliminates the need to worry about escaping characters and such. It works great. :)